# How is the dividend payment calculated when an asset is disposed on the ex date?

Tags: dividends

Example:

```
XYZ Corp pays a $0.25/share dividend - Ex date=1/15/13, Pay date 1/31/2013
I own 100 total shares of XYZ on 1/1/2013
I buy 50 shares of XYZ on at 12 PM 1/15/2013 (increasing total shares to 150)
I buy 50 more shares of XYZ at 1 PM on 1/15/2013 (increasing total shares to 200)
I dispose of all 200 shares of XYZ at 4PM on 1/15/2013 (decreasing total shares to 0)
```

On 1/31/2013, what is my dividend payment worth?

- 25.00 (using balance of 100 on **start** of *ex date*:1/15/2013)
- 37.50 / 50.00 (using balances of 150 and 200 **during** *ex date*:1/15/2013)
- Nothing (because I didn't own it at the end of *ex date*: 1/15/2013)
- Something else entirely

Comment: I doubt this question fits the Quant.SE format. I suppose [Money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com) would be a better place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get nothing, by this logic you could accumulate risk-free money all day by buying/selling on the ex-date as long as the dividend is larger than the spread.